# How can I use bash autocomplete functions and filter patterns together?

Tags: bash, autocomplete

My `bash` correctly autocompletes commands (e.g. `find`, `git`, etc.), but this seems to break as soon as I use filters to prevent completion of certain file patterns, e.g.:

```
complete -f -X '*.@(cmi|cmo)' git
```

The above should prevent autocompletion from selecting filenames matching `*.cmi` and `*.cmo` for `git`.  This does indeed work as intended.  Unfortunately, this also breaks autocompletion of `git` commands and flags.  Switching the order of loading the completion files and the above definition does not seem to matter.

Any ideas on how to make both features work together?

Answer (score 0):

You've instructed bash to use the built-in file completion mechanism for `git`, instead of calling the external completion function that understands the syntax of the `git` command. There's just one completion mechanism, not a series of filters. If you want a series of filters, you have to code it up.

Fortunately, the  2.7-kLoC git completion script does support excluding patterns from `git add` in the natural way: add these patterns to `.gitignore`.

```
printf '%s\n' '*.cm[aiox]' '*.cmxa' '*.[ao]' >>.gitignore
```

If you want to excludes files from `git add` completion without adding them to git's ignore list, I think you'll have to dive into the git completion script. `_git_add` calls `__git_complete_index_file` which calls `__git_index_files` to generate the list of candidate files, and it in turn calls `__git_ls_files_helper` which calls `git ls-files` with the options that were passed all the way down from `_git_add`. So in `_git_add` you could change

```
    __git_complete_index_file "--others --modified --directory --no-empty-directory"
```

to add some options like `--exclude=*.cm[aiox]` (beware of quoting issues: the wildcards are eventually spliced into the command, so `-x *.cm[aiox]` wouldn't work because the pattern would be expanded in the current directory).